# Matplotlib: Plots in Loop appear again at end of Loop

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, plot

I'm getting into Python and managed to create a Loop, which plots different data and is updating every loopcount.
But, after the loop end, all plots appear again at the bottom of the output.
So, it shows my plots at z=0,1,2,3,... and stops at the last z-value, then all plots for all z-values show below the final plot. I'm using python 3.6 with Jupyter.

```
for k in range(0,size(z),50):
    figure()
    w=z[k]
    name = "file_%s.png" % k
    name2 = "z = %s, Index = %s" % (z[k],k)
    title(name2)
    imshow(I[:,:,k], cmap=plt.cm.YlGnBu_r)
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    display.display(pl.gcf())
    savefig(name)
    time.sleep(0.1)

print('End of Loop')
```

Comment: It would be useful if you made this a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try using `plt.show()` instead of `display.display(pl.gcf())`.

You might have to add `%matplotlib inline` to the first row of your cell.

Also: It seems you're using iPython, please add that as a tag.
Plus by convention pyplot is imported as `plt` not as `pl`

Comment: I used this before, but then in Jupyter the output always disappears/immedeatly reappears with the new plot and its not nice to look at this.

Comment: you could put it after the loop, then it would only flash once.